# why are these entry boxes not outputting their values?

Tags: python, tkinter

so I am trying to get the user to enter a date which will then be returned in a later function.here is some example code for this:

```
import Tkinter as tk
global e1
        HEIGHT = 700
        WIDTH = 800
        #these two lines define the dimensions of the window

        canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height = HEIGHT, width = WIDTH)
        canvas.pack()  #packs these dimensions in to the canvas

        frame = tk.Frame(root, bg = '#8BDFF4') #creates the frame and defines the colour of the frame
        frame.place(relx = 0.1, rely = 0.1, relwidth = 0.8, relheight = 0.5) #defines the dimesions of the frame

        e1 = tk.Entry(frame)
        e1.place(relx = 0, rely = 0, relwidth = 0.25,relheight = 0.25)
        e1.pack()
```

this creates an entry box called e1 which the user enters their date. however when I try and run this code it has a strange output:

```
def output():
    get = e1.get()
    print(get)
```

when this function runs the entry box no longer seems to have the date inside of it although I am looking at it and it is still there. when printing 'get' it outputs something that looks like this `.!frame2.!entry` im not really sure why this is the case as it should work. if anybody here could help it would be great

Comment: `e1.get` just names a method of the Entry; actually calling it would be written `e1.get()`.

Comment: @jasonharper sorry that was a typo yeah in my original code it is written ```get()```

Comment: Your updated code should not get `.!frame2.!entry` when executing `print(get)`.

Comment: the indents are incorrect (which i presume is a typo). Also `root` is not defined before it is called...

Comment: presume you want something like:  `root = Tkinter.Tk()` before calling root.

Comment: The code you posted absolutely will _not_ print something like `.!frame2.!entry`.